# Long time transit in Schiphol - will I need to collect my bag?

Tags: transit, amsterdam, klm

I have aprox 20 hours transit in Amsterdam schiphol. My plan is to visit centraal amsterdam and book one night room in a hotel. I have two main question;

1) Will I be able to collect my boarding for the second flight from the first airport? or should I check in again in amsterdam airport 2-3 hours before the second flight?

2) What about my luggage, can I collect it in Amsterdam or it will go directly to the final destination?

Note: I bought the ticket as one trip, not 2 separate trips. the whole flight is with KLM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to collect your bags for the layover, then you will only check in for the first flight and only get the boarding pass for the first flight.

But KLM will check you all the way through to your final destination and hold your bags during the layover.

So the option is yours.